# Login to single tabPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, authentication, shiny

I have been trying to make a login for a single tabPanel in Shiny. I have used the shinyAlert method, (as described here: [How to access Shiny tab ids for use with shinyalerts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120573/how-to-access-shiny-tab-ids-for-use-with-shinyalerts)) which works, but unfortunately, it shows parts of the tabPanel's content before the user is logged in.
Is there a way to change this? I am trying to figure out how to make the "backdrop" of the shinyAlert just a white page until the user is successfully logged in. I read that this might be possible with CSS, but it is unclear to me how.
Or is there another method to do this, that I haven't considered? I am pretty new to Shiny. 
Edit: the relevant parts of the code.

```
ui <- fluidPage(navbarPage("Eksempel", theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                   tabPanel("Home", icon = icon("home"),
                     fluidRow(
                       box(
                        Title = "Welcome to the example layout",
                        width = 10, 
                        solidHeader = TRUE,
                        "Welcome text")
                        )),
                   tabPanel("Prototype", icon = ("chart-line"),
                            fluidPage(tagList(
                              textInput("user", "User:"),
                              passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
                            uiOutput("secrets"))),
                   # other tabPanels

server <- function(input, output, session){ 
  output$secrets <- renderUI({
    req(input$user == "admin", input$password == "shiny")
    
    fluidPage( #contents of tabPanel, containing different plots ect.
     )
})
```

The contents of the fluidPage I am trying to hide works fine when I don't try to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `req` in combination with a `renderUI` and `uiOutput` to hide stuff until someone authenticates.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    textInput("user", "User:"),
    passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
    uiOutput("secrets")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$secrets <- renderUI({
    req(input$user == "admin", input$password == "stackoverflow")
    wellPanel("Hello admin! These are the secrets!")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you want a more enterprise-ready approach, you can try ShinyProxy or Shiny-Server Pro.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I forgot the "wellPanel", once I added it it worked.